# Determine which version of a gem is installed?

Tags: ruby, gem

Is there a way via CLI to determine which version number of a gem is installed on my machine? Similar to `yolk -l` for python?

I'm trying to see if I have the latest version of compass / sass / zurb foundation. I have a dependency that requires a particular version number. So I need to see what version it is.

Comment: Off-Topic: wth is `yolk`? Sounds like a knock-off `pip`!

Comment: @Oli yolk is a python package that shows you what packages are installed in your virtualenv (I don't know anything about python)

Comment: @Oli but it won't show what version number :(

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112754/determining-which-rubygem-youre-using

Answer (score 95, accepted):

```
gem list
```

should give you a list of all your gems with version number in brackets behind it

Answer (score 14):

[StackOverflow has the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340578/sudo-gem-update-dry-run) and it might be a more useful place (for you) for Ruby architecture questions (they're still welcome here)

```
gem outdated
```

Not being a Ruby dev or having any gems installed, I'm not sure this is going to give you exactly what you're after but it should show you which ones need attention.

Otherwise I would have suggested `gem query <package>` (searches local) and `gem query --remote` to see available versions. If you only need local gem versions, the first aught to do.

Answer (score 11):

If your gem's name is `compass`, then you could run:

```
gem list | grep compass
```

It will give you a list of gems, containing the phrase `compass`, and corresponding versions.

Comment: You can also just do `gem list compass`

Answer (score 9):

You can do it like this:

```
bundle info { gem name }
```

Or look in `Gemfile.lock`:

```
grep { gem name } Gemfile.lock
```

Answer (score 5):

To add to @Belogron’s answer you can use

```
gem list MyGem
```

To list the installed versions of MyGem

You can then type

```
gem which MyGem
```

To display the specific version that is being used.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it as follow:

`bundle info <gem name>`

Answer (score 0):

```
gem -v
```

It works for me. Checked in deepin 15.9.1(debian distro)

Comment: What does this do?